# Is there a strong relation with bools and Prop in Coq?

Tags: coq

Is there any means of converting Prop to bool? I know that `forall a b : nat, a <? b -> a < b`, but is this thing is valid at all: `forall a b: nat, a < b -> a <? b`? If not, are there any restrictions I should add, to make this real? And, for other operators that have both `Prop` and `bool` counterparts, can they be converted in such way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a relation between a predicate in `Prop` and one in `bool` means that the property in question is *decidable*. Basically you have a function which decides if the property is `true` or `false`.

This is not the case for all propositions (unless you assume some principle that entails it) but does hold for `<?` and `<`.
This relation is usually crystallised thanks to the `reflect` predicate.

```
Inductive reflect (P : Prop) : bool -> Set :=
| ReflectT : P -> reflect P true 
| ReflectF : ~ P -> reflect P false.
```

In your case you have

```
Nat.ltb_spec0: forall x y : nat, reflect (x < y) (x <? y)
```

I encourage you to look it up.